# Is this ideal two-sided?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose R is a ring with identity and J is the left ideal of R generated by $\{ab - ba: a, b \in R\}$. Does J always have to be a two-sided ideal?

I failed to construct the counterexample, but I do not know how to prove this statement either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It suffices to show that given any element $[a,b]=ab-ba$, the element $(ab-ba)r\in J$ for all $a,b,r\in R$.

We have $$\begin{align*}(ab-ba)r&=abr-bar\\&=abr-arb+arb-bar\\&=a[b,r]+[ar,b]\end{align*}$$
which is in $J$ because $J$ is a left ideal.